# Page not found in Mura

Tags: content-management-system, mura

I have been searching for a solution to my problem with Mura, but to no avail. Unfortunately, I need to use Mura because this site must be made with coldfusion, and so far it is the only CMS that makes the most sense to me. I'm not a web designer / developer at all, and I need a website made immediately :(

The problem is that I get a "page not found" error when viewing my supbages. It looks like this:
http://www.melsa.org/default.cfm

I have asked on the mura support forums this question, and have received a tweak that displays an http:404 error instead of the above. That is a nicer display page, but I would appreciate it if someone could provide a solution to the error. Here is what I have posted on mura about this problem:
http://www.getmura.com/forum/messages.cfm?threadid=9BDC368B-4769-422B-B88ED68CAB010AB9

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your site is looking for the page inside the 'admin' directory... should it be?

> Page /default.cfm [/home/admin/mura/default.cfm] not found

Secondly, as Matt said on the Mura forum, this isn't the way Mura usually handles URLs.
Your page would be at yoursite.com/index.cfm/pagename (If you use some rewriting rules to eliminate the 'index.cfm', it would just be yoursite.com/pagename)

So obviously, there's more to the story in terms of your modifications, or what you have going on behind the scenes.

I recommend starting with a new Mura installation, making sure the 'normal' pages work the way the are supposed to, and then step by step, testing as you go, add your application to the working setup. If you are methodical in your approach you'll know which step breaks the site, and can post back here with details.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is the exact error I personally receive:

`Page /MuraCMS/index.cfm/something-else/index.cfm [***\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\MuraCMS\index.cfm\something-else\index.cfm] not found.`
 

I am building this website locally, so there isn't any ".com" involved in my addresses. I believe Mura specifically has a problem with searching for files after "index.cfm". But that isn't my problem, as I haven't tampered with Mura, and this is the 2nd time I've reinstalled it; I still receive that error when creating subpages :(